# EllipticArcSegment in SceneView

Tags: wpf, sceneview

I want to create an arc in an SceneView. People told me I have to use EllipticArcSegment, and it works in MapView, but I can use it in SceneView. When I use EllipticArcSegment in ScenView I get a line not an arc. See the picture.

```
public MainWindow()
{
InitializeComponent();
MySceneView.Scene = new Scene(BasemapStyle.ArcGISImageryStandard);
MyMapView.Map = new Map(BasemapStyle.ArcGISTopographic);

MapPoint _spain = new MapPoint(-4.00475, 40.637861, SpatialReferences.Wgs84);
Graphic _arc = CreateArc(_spain, 0.080, 90.0, 45.0);
Graphic _arc1 = CreateArc(_spain, 0.080, 90.0, 45.0);
_AiminginZone_GO.Graphics.Add(_arc);
_AiminginZone_GO1.Graphics.Add(_arc1);
MyMapView.GraphicsOverlays.Add(_AiminginZone_GO);
MySceneView.GraphicsOverlays.Add(_AiminginZone_GO1);
}

private Graphic CreateArc(MapPoint center, double radius, double arcAngle, double azimuth)
{

_AiminginZone_GO.Graphics.Clear();
_AiminginZone_GO1.Graphics.Clear();
// set up spatial references
SpatialReference wgs84 = SpatialReferences.Wgs84;
SpatialReference webMercator = SpatialReferences.WebMercator;
// make a point in lat/long (WGS84)
MapPoint centrePoint = new MapPoint(center.X, center.Y, 56, wgs84);
MapPoint centrePoint1 = new MapPoint(center.X+0.05, center.Y, 56, wgs84);
// project it to a mercator projection where the unit of measure is metres
MapPoint mercatorPoint = (MapPoint)GeometryEngine.Project(centrePoint, webMercator);
// create an arc segment which is 50Kilometers radius, starting at 90 degrees, the arc angle is 45 degrees clockwise
//EllipticArcSegment arcSegment = new EllipticArcSegment(centrePoint, mercatorPoint, (Math.PI / 180) * 90, true, true, (Math.PI / 180) * 90, (Math.PI / 180) * -45, wgs84);
EllipticArcSegment arcSegment = EllipticArcSegment.CreateCircularEllipticArc(mercatorPoint, 50000, (Math.PI / 180) * 90, (Math.PI / 180) * -45, webMercator);

// make a part with the segment
Part part = new Part(webMercator);
part.Add(arcSegment);

// create the line from the part
Polyline line = new Polyline(part);

// add it to a graphic and graphics overlay to allow us to visualise it
var polylineSymbol = new SimpleLineSymbol(SimpleLineSymbolStyle.Dash, System.Drawing.Color.Red, 3.0);
Graphic arcGraphic = new Graphic(line, polylineSymbol);
return arcGraphic;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLDHH.jpg)

Comment: If somebody wants to see the problem about this, pleasee see the following link https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-runtime-sdk-for-net-questions/ellipticarcsegment-in-sceneview/m-p/1200695#M11231

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug using EllipticArcSegment.CreateCircularEllipticArc, please see the link to have more informat.
[enter link description here](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-runtime-sdk-for-net-questions/ellipticarcsegment-in-sceneview/m-p/1200695#M11231)